# Create Java Desktop Notification

Tags: java, push-notification, notifications, desktop-application

The requirement is to create a desktop notification which can register a click-event. I cannot use web-sockets or any browser notifications.
I am unable to use Tray-Icons and SystemTray because they cannot register **Click-Events on DISPLAY MESSAGE**. They can have click-events on the trayicon but not on the display message.  The closest example - "When we register a click on a Skype message, it opens Skype for us"

Screenshot

---

[image: Skype Notification Pop-Up]

---

On clicking the above Notification Skype chat opens-up. The same functionality is not supported with Tray-Icons. Either a work around it or a new approach will be do.
Hope I am clear thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used the following repository from github [DorkBox](https://github.com/dorkbox/Notify).
Simply add maven dependency as instructed on the github link. However, I was unable to check how to change the UI for the notifications.

```
Notify.create()
      .title(text)
      .text(title)
      .position(Pos.TOP_RIGHT)
      .onAction( new ActionHandler<Notify>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Notify value) {
                if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported() && Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
                    try {
                        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(targetUrl));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
      })
      .hideAfter(5000)
      .shake(250, 5)
      .darkStyle()      // There are two default themes darkStyle() and default.
      .showConfirm();   // You can use warnings and error as well.
```

Add the following code in your main block and you are good to go.